# Data type to save coordinates

Tags: qgis, coordinates

What's a proper data type to save coordinates in QGIS when using the 'Move label' tool?

```
real
double
numeric()
...
```

**EDIT:**

The CRS of the project is MGI / Austria GK East (31256).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to coordinates, always use `double` type if your data store allows you to. The reason is simple - it is always better to have higher positional precision (which you can round down if needed).

Answer (score 5):

Decimal (Real), just wit enough decimals to store the resulting coordinates. If you try to move points in a geographic coordinate system like 4326 it will need at least 6 decimals after the point. For projected CRS, that is up to you